# copy a whole application to new application visual C++ MFC/Smart Device?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-mobile, mfc, visual-studio-2005

I am using Visual studio 2005 for my development. I am  doing a smart device application using Visual C++ MFC.

I had an application runnning perfectly on a device with ARMV4, till recently we receive a new Device with ARMV4I. the application is running on the new device but some features are not working, mainly serial port communications.

I compiled the existing application to new ARMV4I but still doesnt work.

I had an idea to create a new application and choose ARMV4I using the wizards, and then then compile it to use in my device..I have some trouble doing that!

My question is how to create a new application and copy/add/insert the old files, images, dialogs, headers and others from the old one and make it works.

if you have idea, please give some detailed information.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer for your question, rather, another procedure to follow to achieve your goal.

1. Create two dummy projects with exactly the same name; one for ARMV4I and the other for ARMV4.
2. Compare the resulting .vcproj files (they are XMLs) using a visual diff'ing tool (e.g. [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org))
3. Identify the changes between them that makes one work and the other not
4. Apply these changes to your existing project. It should work now.

If you still need to copy files into your new project, just copy your .cpp / .h / .rc / res files into their appropriate directories and edit your .vcproj file manually to reflect these new files.